# Error Uncaught TypeError: title.addEventListener is not a function al mostrar el titulo en tiempo real

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando mostrar el titulo en tiempo real mientras escribo mi post en mi blog pero me esta lanzando un error que no logro solucionar. Lo que quiero hacer es justo lo mismo que hace este foro que mientras escribo en el textarea me muestra más abajo lo que escribo, solo que yo quiero lograr justo eso pero en con el titulo.

### HTML:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <title id="titlePost"> |Crear entrada</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize-icons.css" />
```

### Código JavaScript:

```js
const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
title.addEventListener('keypress', evento);

function evento(e) {
    document.getElementById('titlePost').innerText = title.value;
}
```

[image: Imagen del error que me muestra]

Espero que hayan entendido con claridad lo que quiero lograr, si necesitan saber otra información solo déjamelo saber. *Gracias*

Comment: Un detalle, por si no lo conocías: el título del documento lo tienes disponible en [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title), por lo tanto no hay necesidad de asignarle un identificador para acceder a él.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que sufres es que estás accediendo al `value` del elemento y no al elemento en sí:

```
const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
```

Por lo que a un `String`, que es una cadena de caracteres, no se le puede agregar un manipulador de eventos mediante `addEventListener()`. El método `addEventListener()` no existe en la clase `String` y por eso el error te indica que dicha función no existe.

Este mismo error te saldría si pruebas:

```
"Cadena de pruebas".addEventListener("hola");
```

Además, es posible que no puedas encontrar el ID si tu código JavaScript se ejecuta ANTES de que se haya generado el DOM porque lo estás cargando incluso antes del HTML que busca a través del ID.

Para solucionarlo puedes encapsular tu código en un manipulador del evento [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

```
/* Agregamos un manipulador para el evento DOMContentLoaded */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (ev) => {
    /* Ahora buscamos el elemento con esa ID (sin el .value) */
    const title = document.getElementById('title');
    title.addEventListener('keypress', evento);
    
    function evento(e) {
        document.getElementById('titlePost').innerText = title.value;
    }
});
```

También puedes cargar el código javascript mediante un `defer`:

```
<script src="posts.js" defer></script>
```

Por último, indicarte que puedes ahorrarte multitud de llamadas a `getElementById()`, JavaScript crea una variable de ámbito global y bajo `window` por cada ID generado en el DOM:

```
/* Agregamos un manipulador para el evento DOMContentLoaded */
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (ev) => {
    /* Ya existe "title", no tenemos que buscarlo */
    title.addEventListener('keypress', evento);
    
    function evento(e) {
        /* También existe "titlePost" sin necesidad de buscarlo */
        titlePost.innerText = title.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Me esta saliendo este error *Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list* aun sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Me faltó un paréntesis para cerrar el `window.addEventListener()`, ya está arreglado.